# Angularjs: count variable of a scope passed as a param of function is not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am refactoring some code and have a small issue. I am passing a count variable of the scope to a func and incrementing it but the original value is not updated. Here is a sample:

```
angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.counter = 0;
      $scope.change = function(counter) {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        console.log($scope.counter);
      };
    }]);

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change(counter)" id="ng-change-example1" />
  <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
</div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/f6fle98TSmINuD6CCz3Q?p=preview

You can see the output in the console.

Can You offer me some solution?

Comment: I think your code is working well so i asume i don't understand your question. What i anderstand is: 1. `$scope.counter=0` 2. `change(counter)` 3. Function recives `$scope.counter=0` so `counter=0` 4. `counter++` 5. Ends with `counter=1`. ¿What am I misising?

Comment: yes counter is 1, but $scope.counter is 0

Comment: Of course, you are not changing it's value at any time. If you want to increase it `$scope.counter++` is the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code

```
  <body ng-app="changeExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.counter = 0;
      vm.change = function(counter) {
        vm.counter++;
        console.log(counter);
      };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController as e">
  {{e.counter}}
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="e.change(e.counter)" id="ng-change-example1" />
  <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: please read carefully my question again, I do not want to just $scope.counter ++, but pass the scope value through the function and increment it from there. I cannot just do $scope.counter++ in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Please instead of `counter++` inside the change-function use `$scope.counter++`. The answer to your question why original value is not updated is that you are not updating the scope (`$scope.counter`) in your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are mixing variables because its name. Maybe changing `counter` variable name can help you:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngChange-directive-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="changeExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.counter = 0;
      $scope.change = function(variable) {
        variable++;
        console.log(variable);
        console.log($scope.counter);
      };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change(counter)" id="ng-change-example1" />
  <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The right way is update $scope.counter value:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ngChange-directive-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="changeExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('changeExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.counter = 0;
      $scope.change = function(counter) {
        $scope.counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        console.log($scope.counter);
      };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change(counter)" id="ng-change-example1" />
  <label for="ng-change-example2">Confirmed</label><br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this help!